# Interchange max and sup.

Tags: real-analysis

Here, $\|f \|_{max} = \max_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$. Is the following true?

\begin{align}
\sup_{\|f\|_{max} = 1} \max_{x \in [a,b]} \left|\int_a^b G(x,y) f(y) dy \right| = \max_{x \in [a,b]} \left|\int_a^b G(x,y) dy \right|.
\end{align}
I believe so, since $\|f\|_{max} = 1$ implies $\int G f \leq \int G 1$ and furthermore it seems obvious that $f(y) = 1$ is the best choice for maximizing the integral. Is there any serious justification that needs to be done, or am I overthinking things?

EDIT: Also, the only assumptions on $f$ and $G$ are continuity.

Comment: The issue is that $G$ can be negative.

Comment: Doesn't the absolute value sign eliminate that problem immediately, or am I mistaken? $|\int G | = | \int - G |$

Comment: The absolute value is outside the integral so it doesn't resolve the problem. In fact, the absolute value does nothing here because if the integral is ever negative you can replace $f$ with $-f$. The issue is, if say $f(y) = 1/2$, then $G(x,y)f(y) \le G(x,y)$ only when $G(x,y) \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $Gf \le G1$ only holds when $G$ is non-negative. If $G$ has negative values, we want to define $f$ as

$$
 f(y) = \begin{cases}
          1 & G(x,y) \ge 0 \\
          -1 & G(x,y) < 0
        \end{cases}.
$$

Then $Gf = |G|$ and we should have

\begin{align}
\sup_{\|f\|_{max} = 1} \max_{x \in [a,b]} \left|\int_a^b G(x,y) f(y) dy \right| = \max_{x \in [a,b]} \int_a^b |G(x,y)| dy.
\end{align}

---

To address your concern, it is true that

$$ \sup_{a \in A} \sup_{b \in B} F(a,b) = \sup_{(a,b) \in A \times B} F(a,b) = \sup_{b \in B} \sup_{a \in A} F(a,b). $$

Let us prove the first equality and the second follows symmetrically.

Let $S_1 = \sup_{a \in A} \sup_{b \in B} F(a,b)$ and $S_2 = \sup_{(a,b) \in A \times B} F(a,b)$. Suppose that $S_1 < S_2$. Then, since $S_2$ is the least upper bound of the set $\{F(a,b) : (a,b) \in A \times B\}$, there exist $(a_0, b_0) \in A \times B$ with $S_1 < F(a,b)$. But then

$$ F(a_0,b_0) \le \sup_{b \in B} F(a_0,b) \le \sup_{a \in A} \sup_{b \in B} F(a,b) = S_1, $$

a contradiction.

Next, suppose that $S_2 < S_1$. Then, because $S_1$ is the least upper bound of $\{\sup_{b \in B} F(a,b) : a \in A\}$, it follows that there is some $a_0 \in A$ such that $S_2 < \sup_{b \in B} F(a_0,b)$. Similarly, there now exists $b_0 \in B$ such that $S_2 < F(a_0,b_0)$, a contradiction.

---

With that out of the way, let us see why we end up with $|G(x,y)|$ inside our integral since the function $f$ that we defined may not be continuous.

**If you want to figure out how to obtain $|G(x,y)|$ by using *continuous* functions by yourself, stop reading here.**

To do this, we want to approximate $f$ by a continuous function. To do this, we will want to partition $[a,b]$ into a collection of intervals such that on each interval, either $G \ge 0$ or $G < 0$. Then, we put $\varepsilon$ small gaps between the intervals and interpolate $f$ linearly.

The set $\{y \in [a,b] : G(x,y) < 0\}$ is relatively open in $[a,b]$. So it is of the form $U \cap [a,b]$ for some open set $U$ in $\mathbf R$. By [this question](//math.stackexchange.com/q/318299/), every open set in $\mathbf R$ is an at most countable union of disjoint intervals. Thus we have some countable collection of disjoint intervals $(I_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ such that $G(x,y) < 0$ on each $I_n$ and $G(x,y) \ge 0$ if $y \notin \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty I_n$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Now shrink each interval $I_n$ by some positive $\varepsilon_n$ and define $f = 1$ on the shrinked intervals, $f = -1$ on the complement of $\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty I_n$ and interpolated linearly in the gaps. Choose $\varepsilon_n$ such that the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \varepsilon_n = \varepsilon$. For example, $\varepsilon_n = \varepsilon/2^n$.

By construction, the function $G(x,y)f(y)$ agreees with $|G(x,y)|$ except on the gaps, which have a total length of less than $\varepsilon$. On the gaps, the difference $||G(x,y)| - G(x,y)f(y)| \le |G(x,y)| + |G(x,y)||f(y)| \le 2|G(x,y)|$. By the extreme value theorem, $|G(x,y)|$ is bounded by some $M$. Therefore

$$ \left| \int_a^b |G(x,y)|dy - \int_a^b G(x,y)f(y) dy \right| = \left| \int_{\text{gaps}} |G(x,y)| - G(x,y)f(y) dy \right| \le 2M\varepsilon. $$

Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we get an integral over $|G(x,y)|$ in the supremum.

Comment: Also, I appreciate the spoiler warning.